# Excel VBA Current Range in Collection

Tags: excel, vba

Using the code below I have been able to obtain the indented BOM for any parent item (specified in cell D1). Screen shot below shows the indented bom in columns D, E & F obtained for item A based of the Parent / Child relationships listed in columns A and B. I would like to expand this slightly so that the associated qty of each child item is shown in column G. I was trying to obtain the address corresponding to vChild and then offset by 1 column but I have had no success.

Any ideas appreciated

[image]

```
Public collRoot As Collection

Sub DisplayTree()
Dim coll As Collection
Dim rParents As Range, rNode As Range
Dim rOut As Range, sRootNode As String, lRow As Long
Dim rLevels As Range, rLevel As Range
Dim level As Integer, maxLevels As Integer, cur As Integer, i As Integer
Dim h As String, counts() As Integer

    Set collRoot = Nothing
    Set collRoot = New Collection
    Set rParents = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown))

    ' Store the tree in a collection
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each rNode In rParents
        Set coll = Nothing
        Set coll = collRoot(rNode.Value)
        If coll Is Nothing Then collRoot.Add New Collection, rNode.Value
        collRoot(rNode.Value).Add rNode.Offset(, 1).Value
    Next rNode

    sRootNode = Range("D1")
    Range("D2") = 0
    Range("F2") = sRootNode
    Set rOut = Range("D2")

    Call DisplayTree1(sRootNode, rOut, lRow, 1)

'   Calculate Levels
    Set rLevels = Range("D3:D" & Range("D3").End(xlDown).Row)
    maxLevels = WorksheetFunction.Max(rLevels)
    ReDim counts(1 To maxLevels)

    cur = 1
    For Each rLevel In rLevels
        level = rLevel.Value
        h = ""
        counts(level) = counts(level) + 1
        For i = 1 To level
            h = h & "." & counts(i)
        Next
        h = Mid(h, 2)
        For i = level + 1 To UBound(counts)
            counts(i) = 0
        Next
        rLevel.Offset(, 1).Value = h
        cur = level
    Next

End Sub

Sub DisplayTree1(ByVal sParent As String, rOut As Range, _
                ByRef lRow As Long, ByVal lLevel As Long)
Dim vChild, coll As Collection

    On Error Resume Next
    For Each vChild In collRoot(sParent)
        lRow = lRow + 1
        rOut.Offset(lRow, 2) = vChild
        rOut.Offset(lRow, 0) = lLevel
        Set coll = Nothing
        Set coll = collRoot(vChild)
        If Not coll Is Nothing Then Call DisplayTree1(vChild, rOut, lRow, lLevel + 1)
    Next vChild
End Sub
```

Comment: In your example, `F` (in `Child` column) has a quantity of both 5 and 2. Is this an error in your example data ?

Comment: Hi Robin. Parent Item B uses 5 x F and while Parent D uses 2 x F. In the indented bom for A shown, A uses 5 x D and each D consumes 2 x F. Each F would consume 6 x H. So the first 4 qty would be A x1, D x 5, F x 2 and H x 6. I am not worried about the cumulative totals, just the qty per values.

Answer (score 0):

I have elected to use a workaround using vlookups to obtain the qty values